# Editing Sharepoint 2010 Webpart SSRS report

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Does anyone know how to check out a webpart in Sharepoint 2010.  I have an SSRS report within the Webpart that shows on the front page of the Sharepoint site.

I need to edit the web part.  I only need to edit or add to the ***"Show navigation bar the navigation controls and Show Back Button"***.

When I check these 2 boxes and click APPLY I get an error message ***"Cannot save all of the property settings for this Web Part. The file is not checked out. You must first check out this document before making changes."***

I have full control on the site, but not sure how to check out the web-part to edit and add these 2 buttons to the navigation of the report.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out through this link...[Customize Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-a-Web-Part-Page-99d79209-264f-41fc-86d6-5612485bdf9b)

I went to libraries and then Pages and found the Home page and checked it out.